# relative URI reference in XSLT-stylesheets

Tags: xml, xslt

I have these directories:

[image]

Catalog 1836_561 contains five xml-files:

[image]

Standing in 1836_561 I can get the name of the author in 1836_561_intro.xml transforming 1836_561_txt.xml using this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="document(//note[@type='intro']/@target)//author">
```

1836_561_txt.xml contains this element:

```
<note target="1836_561_intro.xml" type="intro"/>
```

Catalog 1836_562 contains four xml-files:

[image]

How do I get the name of the author in 1836_561/1836_561_intro.xml standing in 1836_562 transforming 1836_562_txt.xml? Is it possible?

Comment: Which version of XSLT do you use? In XSLT 2 or 3 you have access to functions like http://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/fn/resolve-uri.html and http://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/fn/base-uri.html so it should be possible to resolve a relative URI. You haven't really explained which value you have in the file `1836_562_txt.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

If you process `1836_562_txt.xml` then `document-uri(/)` should give you its absolute URI, then you can use `resolve-uri('../1836_561/1836_561_txt.xml', document-uri(/))` to get the URI of the other file in the other folder and then e.g. `doc(resolve-uri('../1836_561/1836_561_txt.xml', document-uri(/)))` to load that file and `doc(doc(resolve-uri('../1836_561/1836_561_txt.xml', document-uri(/))))//note[@type='intro']/@target)` to load the referenced file respectively then `doc(doc(resolve-uri('../1836_561/1836_561_txt.xml', document-uri(/))))//note[@type='intro']/@target)//author` to select the `autor` elements in the referenced file.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it later this week. I hope I may come back with questions in case I can't make it work.